# Showing symmetry of a relation between a commutative identity ring and a multiplicative subset of the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

R is a commutative ring with identity, not necessarily an integral domain, and S is a multiplicative subset of R\0 containing 1 which is closed under multiplication. A relation ~ is defined on R x S so that $(r_1,s_1)$ ~ $(r_2,s_2)$ if and only if there exists an element t of S so that $t(r_1s_2 – r_2s_1) = 0$. I am trying to show that this relation is an equivalence relation, and I have everything but symmetry, which is tripping me up a little bit.

I know that if $(r_1, s_1)$ ~ $(r_2, s_2)$, then there exists a t in S so that $t(r_1s_2 – r_2s_1) = 0$, and it follows that $-t(r_2s_1 – r_1s_2) = 0$, but how can I be sure that -t is in S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-t(r_2s_1 – r_1s_2) = 0$ implies $t(r_2s_1 – r_1s_2) = 0$.

Comment: It looks so obvious now that you've said it. For some reason, I was thinking I couldn't do that because -1 might not be in S, but that doesn't actually matter here, right?

Comment: Yes, of course.